# BoxConstraints forces an infinite width. RenderBox was not laid out

Tags: flutter

```dart
Widget cards(
          {required String img,
          required String title,
          required String price}) =>
      SizedBox(
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        child: Card(
          elevation: 7,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 60,
                    width: 80,
                    child: Image.asset(img, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text(title),
                        trailing: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 8),
                      const Text('1 Piece'),
                      Text(price),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Text(
                          'In stock',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[800]),
                        ),
                        trailing: Switch(
                            activeColor: Colors.green[900],
                            value: val,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                val = value;
                              });
                            }),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              const Divider(
                height: 10,
                color: Colors.grey,
                thickness: 3,
              ),
              const Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.share,
                    size: 18,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Share Product',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
```

what is this error . what are the reasons

Comment: Share error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `ListTile` inside a `Column` inside a `Row`. The `Row` gives unlimited max width. The `Column` passes this down. The `ListTile` wants to fill the whole available width. So as a result, the `ListTile` wants to have an infinite width because it wasn't constrained anywhere above in the widget tree.

You may want to wrap your `Column` in an `Expanded`, which will make the `Column` inside the `Row` fill only the remaining width available after laying out other normal children (not wrapped in `Expanded`/`Flexible`), so in your case after laying out the `SizedBox`.